# Get path to .NET Framework directory in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild, .net-framework-version, microsoft.build

I am trying to use this method to get the .NET Framework directory (e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\v4.0.30319`)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Build.Utilities

$dotNetDir = [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToDotNetFramework([Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion]::VersionLatest)
```

However, it is returning nothing. No error, just blank.

I know there are other ways to get the .NET directory but I am wondering why this method is not working?

Comment: on my win7x64 system running ps5.1, i get version `2.0.5+` but the newest _directory_ is actually `4.0.3+` in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` - the newest installed version in the `4.0.3+` dir is `4.7.3+`. i have no idea why the numbers are so different.

Comment: I tried it on a Windows 7 machine and got the same results, it reports the 2.0 directory when 4 is latest. But I get nothing at all on Windows 10. I guess its just unreliable for some reason.

Comment: @prb - thank you for the feedback ... i was quite curious! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The `Microsoft.Build.Utilities` assembly doesn't support framework versions newer than 2.0.  Use a newer assembly to get support for newer framework versions.

---

On 64-bit Windows 10 Professional I get the following output...

```
PS> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS> [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToDotNetFramework([Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion]::VersionLatest)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
```

I also notice that the `VersionLatest` enumeration value is an alias for `Version20`...

```
PS> [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion]::VersionLatest
Version20
```

That is, `VersionLatest` evidently doesn't mean "find the latest installed framework version at runtime", it's just a flexible way to specify the latest available version *known at compile-time* (of that `Microsoft.Build.Utilities` assembly), of which there are not many...

```
PS> $enumType = [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion]
PS> [Enum]::GetNames($enumType) `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $value = $enumType::$_;
        New-Object -TypeName 'PSCustomObject' -Property (
            [Ordered] @{
                Name = $_;
                ValueText = $value;
                ValueInt32 = [Int32] $value
            }
        )
    }

Name          ValueText ValueInt32
----          --------- ----------
Version11     Version11          0
Version20     Version20          1
VersionLatest Version20          1
```

Regarding the results you see on different operating systems, Windows 7 has .NET 2.0 installed by default and, if I recall, Windows 10 has .NET 4.0 but not 2.0 installed by default, so if you didn't change anything that would explain why you get outdated results on Windows 7 and no results on Windows 10.  I do have .NET 2.0 as an installed feature on Windows 10, which is why the method is able to find that framework directory.

To fix this, you need to use a newer `Microsoft.Build.Utilities*` assembly, which uses a new name for each version.  On my system I have `Microsoft.Build.Utilities` and `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5` in the GAC, but the latter only supports up to .NET 3.5.  Instead, I installed [`Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core/)...

```
PS> Install-Package -Name 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core' -ProviderName 'NuGet'
```

After passing `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` and its dependencies to `Add-Type`, I get a much longer list of [`Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.targetdotnetframeworkversion) values using the snippet above...

```
Name              ValueText ValueInt32
----              --------- ----------
Version11         Version11          0
Version20         Version20          1
Version30         Version30          2
Version35         Version35          3
Version40         Version40          4
Version45         Version45          5
Version451       Version451          6
Version46         Version46          7
Version461       Version461          8
Version452       Version452          9
Version462    VersionLatest         10
VersionLatest VersionLatest         10
Version47         Version47         11
Version471       Version471         12
Version472       Version472         13
Latest               Latest       9999
```

Now your original code finally returns the directory for .NET 4.0...

```
PS> [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToDotNetFramework([Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion]::VersionLatest)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

I notice there is a new `Latest` enumeration value as well which [looks like](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/blob/e70a3159d64f9ed6ec3b60253ef863fa883a99b1/src/Tasks/GetFrameworkPath.cs#L73) it really does mean "the version of the latest installed framework", though it (currently) returns the same path as passing `VersionLatest`.

Comment: The command doesnt work to me `Unable to find type [Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper].`

Comment: Have you run the `Add-Type` command from the question?